# How to add a newline every three character in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How can i split a string that contains **|** (pipe) as separator lets after every 3 pipes?

I'll explain better:

i have a string that results in dates, something like this:

```
Tuesday - 23-06-2015| Wednesday - 24-06-2015| Thursday - 25-06-2015| Friday - 26-06-2015| Monday - 29-06-2015| Tuesday - 30-06-2015|
```

And i'd like to add a `<br/>` so that i have only 3 dates on the same line, like this:

```
Tuesday - 23-06-2015| Wednesday - 24-06-2015| Thursday - 25-06-2015|

Friday - 26-06-2015| Monday - 29-06-2015| Tuesday - 30-06-2015|
```

I found this code to count the times the pipe is repeated in the string:

```
var CustomerDatesSplitted = (customerDates.match(/\|/g) || []).length;
console.log(CustomerDatesSplitted ); //Logs 6, the right value
```

and i found this code that needs a specific value to insert in the regex (in this case, adds a new line after 10 charactes:

```
customerDates.match(/.{1,10}/g).join("<br/>");
```

but i don't know the best way to make it "dynamic" so that it checks only the pipes and split after the 3rd, 6th, 9th and so on...

suggestions?

Comment: I don't really understand the downvote...

Comment: Unnecessary downvote, since question was well drafted, full of details and attempted code +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
str = str.replace(/((?:[^|]*\|){3})/g, '$1<br>');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aS9hR0/1)

Comment: anubhava is the King of Regex.